# Area under the curve $1+8/x^2$, between $x=2$ and $x=4$

Tags: integration

The question is as below:

> The area bounded by the $x$-axis, $1+8/x^2$, $x=2$ and $x=4$ is divided into two halves by $x=a$.
>   What is the value of $a$?

I marked the value of a as $2\sqrt2$. My textbook says $-2\sqrt2$ should also be an answer. Should it? Should I consider external division of areas?

Comment: How can the answer be negative? It should belong to $(2,4)$.

Comment: Exactly my thoghts. Just wanted to confirm if external division of area makes sense?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: I agree with @JoséCarlosSantos.

Comment: I don't think the answer is $2\sqrt{2}$ is it? The correct answer would be closer to 3.3, no?

Comment: Apparently not. Solving it gives those two values.

Comment: Ah, yes per your update of the equation to $1+8/x^2$ you are correct. The previous equation $1+8x^2$ gave a different solution.

Comment: Don't they mean that the equation has two solutions, but you still need to discuss their relevance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\int_2^a\left(1+\frac{8}{x^2}\right)dx=a-\frac 8a+2$$
and
$$\int_a^4\left(1+\frac{8}{x^2}\right)dx=-a+\frac 8a+2$$
using the power rule. Now set
$$a-\frac 8a+2=-a+\frac 8a+2$$
and solve to get $a=\pm 2\sqrt 2$.

At no point did we make any assumptions about $a$. However, $f$ is not integrable on an interval containing $0$, so we should assume $a>0$. The book answer also includes a false solution. This is not correct since the integral from $2$ to $-2\sqrt 2$ is not defined.

Note that the integral is not defined in an extended sense using an improper integral either. There truly is only one answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(a-\frac 8a\right)-\left(2-\frac 82\right)=\left(4-\frac 84\right)-\left(a-\frac 8a\right)$$

or after simplification

$$2(a^2-8)=0$$

and indeed $$a=\pm2\sqrt2.$$

I would disagree to accept the negative value because it is not inside $[2,4]$, but also because it would involve areas across a singularity, which is not acceptable.